IntelliJ 2024.3 - error - Could not get unknown property 'GradleVersion'
I installed the latest version of intelliJ on the 18th, and ever since I can no longer Sync Gradle Changes.
Whenever I attempt to the error below is thrown:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating initialization script.
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'GradleVersion'....
at sync_studio_tooling3435_cllv1147ss38zx0z25gq448oz.run(C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.studio.tooling3435.gradle:6)

Any idea why this would be happening? I've no GradleVersion in my build.gradle or any references to sync_studio_tooling....

There's a recent issue with the Android plugin that most likely causes this:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-363320
Workarounds are:

Disable the Android plugin in File | Settings | Plugins
Install the previous version 2024.2.4 of IntelliJ IDEA


not the only problem with 2024.3, sadly. We had to downgrade because it messed up our project structure (ANT project) and the search performance was extremely poor (just browsing to a source package could take 10 minutes, unworkable). Jetbrains notified me they've found the performance problem and a fix is being worked on

disabling the Android plugin fixed this issue - thanks Koyasha!

@jwenting Yes, you are probably referring to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-171550, a bug in the indexing process that has messed up quite a lot of everything. The fix is already being tested on the latest 2024.3 branch. Various workarounds are available in the meantime in the YouTrack issue description at the top.

@Koyasha yes, probably the one. Made 2024.3 impossible to use for me (it might be in part related to plugin loading order too, disabling and reenabling some plugins made things run more smoothly)

I encountered a related bug (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-364838) which restricts me from upgrading to the latest version until both are fixed.
